# How do I convert the perfmon counters in the Performance Monitor to something that can log those for me?

Tags: perfmon

How do I convert the perfmon counters in the Performance Monitor to something that can log those for me?

Do I need to create a data collector set and go back and select each one by hand? I'm trying to avoid doing it by hand, because I'm lazy.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the counters you want selected, Right-click "Performance Monitor" (the red circled bit), and select New, Data Collector Set.  Go through the wizard, and it should have all the counters you selected already populated in there.

Comment: How did I miss THAT?

Comment: To be fair, if you go through it one might think that you'd create a completely new instance and wipe your currently selected counters.  Turns out, not so much :)

Comment: Nice!!  I needed that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your question, you are simply trying to record your Perfmon results into a report.  The method of doing it depends on your OS but if you're using server 2008/Windows Vista/Windows 7 you can either go into **Data Collector Sets->System** and select one of the default data collector sets (then hit the play button to start recording).  These will then record to *%windir%\tracing* by default.

Alternatively You can Right Click the **User Defined** section create a new data collector set.

These reports will end up in **Reports->Sytem (or User Defined if you made a custom one)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sort of. I added a bunch of counters to the -> monitoring Tools -> Performance Monitor and I want to log them a-la a Data Collector Set without having to readd all the counters one by one (that window is kind of clunky)

Comment: I edited my Q so ...

Answer (score 0):

There is not much need to convert anything, Perfmon counters are [available through WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can use any WMI-capable performance collector ([OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) is a popular one which does have [appropriate support](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/WmiConfiguration), although it might appear rather difficult to set up) to turn the data into historic graphs. An alternative is to use [NRPE](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf) as an intermediate layer which is supported by a multitude of other popular monitoring/graphing systems like [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).

Comment: I can see I'm not making myself clear. I don't know how to explain it except in the comments I left on the other answer.

Comment: I edited my Q so ...